# jQuery doesn't work after load

Tags: jquery, load

I got this jQuery code which is working just fine. Except on element I load after the page is ready.

```
$('.reply').click(function(){
  ele = $(this).attr('title');
  $('#'+ele).load('ajax/form_post.php');
  $('#'+ele).show();
  return false;
               });

 $('.add_com form').submit(function(){
  ele = $(this);
  $.post('ajax/com.php',
      { info : ele.parents('.add_com').attr('title'),
        texte : ele.find('textarea').val(),
      }, 
   function(data) {
     if(data == 'xxxx'){
     alert('erreur');
    }
    else{
     ele.parents('.add_com').append(data);
    }
   });
  return false;
                                  });
```

after I loaded the form clicking on  the add_com form doesn't work. It works on form already loaded though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out JQuery's [live method](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Using this allows you to apply your code to anything it sees in the DOM on page load or in the future.

Comment: live is depreciated. Now you have to use jQuery ON.